# Which Google service is responsible for emergency notifications?

Tags: notifications

I have an app that blocks notifications. I want to let emergency warnings through (like tornado warnings).

The services that have google in their name are:

- "Files by Google" - com.google.android.apps.nbu.files
- "Goggles" - com.google.android.apps.unveil
- "Hangouts" - com.google.android.talk
- "Home" - com.google.android.apps.chromecast.app
- "Maps" - com.google.android.apps.maps
- "News & Weather" com.google.andoird.apps.genie.geniewidget - Maybe this is it?
- "Personal Safety" com.google.android.apps.safetyhub
- "Google" - com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox
- "Google Go" - com.google.android.apps.searchlite
- "Google News" - com.google.android.apps.magazines
- "Google Play" - com.google.android.apps.walletnfcrel
- "Google Play Games" - com.google.android.play.games
- "Google Play Music" - com.google.android.music
- "Google Play Store" - come.android.vending
- "Google TV" - com.google.android.videos

I'm using a pixel xl 2.

Also, how do I test if I have the settings correct? Is there a way to fake an emergency broadcast to myself?

Comment: Does Google in USA really send emergency warnings? If they do it is something US specific, because in other countries emergency warnings are sent as some sort of broadcast SMS by the network operator (and thus no Google app is responsible).

Comment: Seconded Robert's comment. Other than Google's own "Personal Safety" (crisis alerts), emergency alerts are usually sent by network operator. You can check the setting on Android Settings - Wireless & networks - More - Emergency broadcasts - Cell Broadcast settings.

Comment: I had a blocked tornado warning yesterday. It was a notification not a text message. 

Andrew, I do not have that menu chain in my phone. So I searched for similar terms. "Emergency" pulled up some results but they are all app settings. "Broadcast" had no results. "Network" didn't have any relevant choices. I do not see any way to choose to receive emergency alerts as text messages instead of notifications on a Pixel XL 2 with Android 11.

Comment: @triplej Searching for "Emergency" on the Settings of my Pixel 3a with Android 11, there should be the "Wireless emergency alerts" section. Note that this is an integrated Android system service though, not by Google.